# Pandoc cannot find image path referenced in external HTML file pulled into R Markdown, despite using here() package

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, pandoc

I am producing an HTML document through R Markdown, which uses a few external HTML documents for headers and footers. I am also using the here() package to allow relative paths throughout my project.
However, when using YAML to include the external HTML through R code, the relative paths within those files do not work.

This is the YAML header of the R Markdown code:

```
---
title: "Test"
output:
  html_document:
    includes:
      in_header: !expr "here::here('FORMATTING','favicon.html')"
---
```

The file 'favicon.html' has the following code:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.ico"/>
```

My folder structure is:

```
Main
│   └──.here
├──SCRIPTS
│   └──test_code.Rmd
├──FORMATTING
│   └──favicon.html
│   └──favicon.ico
```

When I run the script using 'Knit' button in RStudio, I get the following error:

```
File favicon.ico not found in resource path
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 99
```

It seems that pandoc can find the HTML files just fine using there R code, but then it seems to want an absolute file path for the actual image.

How can I ensure pandoc finds the images without having to resort to absolute paths?

Comment: I've found a partial solution, which requires changing the filepaths in the HTML to be relative to the folder where the R script is run. So replacing the HTML code with `<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href=".\..\FORMATTING\favicon.ico"/> ` works.
However, this is not optimal as the path of the R script may change, so would still appreciate any further input.

Answer (score 0):

I habe exactly the same problem. The solution proposed by Modern_ibex (`<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href=".\..\FORMATTING\favicon.ico"/>` ) does not work for me.

My favicon.html and logo.png are stored in folder "Data".
In favicon.html: `"<link rel="shortcut icon" href="Data/logo.png" />"`

```
project.Rproj
|
|___ Data (- favicon.html
|          - logo.png)
|
|___ Scripts
           |__ Rmds (- my file.rmd)
           |
           |__ ...
```

My rmd file is stored in "Scripts/Rmds".
My YAML looks like:

```
title: "Analysis"
author: "me"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d. %B %Y')`"
output:
  html_document:
    includes:
      in_header: !expr here::here("Data/favicon.html")
```

when running I get an error message:
**File Data/logo.png not found in resource path
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 99**
So favicon.html is read but the href is not interpreted. I tried divers href in favicon.html with ~ or . or .. or / or \ or r code but no results.

thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

In `.Rmd YAML`:

```
title: "Analysis"
author: "me"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d. %B %Y')`"
output:
  html_document:
    includes:
      in_header: !expr here::here("Data/favicon.html")
```

In `favicon.html`:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../Data/logo.png" />
```

File structure:

```
project.Rproj
|
|___ Data (- favicon.html
|          - logo.png)
|
|___ Scripts
           |__ Rmds (- my file.rmd)
           |
           |__ ...
```